# How to get the application data from Chrome DevTools using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-devtools

I am new to Selenium. I am trying to get data from the application part of Chrome DevTools, dynamically, using python.

I got started using the below code:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from pprint import pprint
import json

yoururl = "https://yourlink.com"

caps = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
caps['goog:loggingPrefs'] = {'performance': 'ALL'}
#driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=caps)
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(yoururl)
time.sleep(5) # wait for all the data to arrive. 
perf = driver.get_log('performance')
#pprint(perf)
print(json.dumps(perf, indent=4))
```

Please note that I am new.

Comment: Can you specify what data are you trying to get? Is that Response for some request? Is that object in response? Does it have known url or url part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this :

```
var localStorageData = {};
for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
    var key = localStorage.key(i);
    var value = localStorage.getItem(key);
    localStorageData[key] = value;
}
return localStorageData;
```

create a variable and set its value to these codes as a string and run it in `driver.execute`.

Like this :

```
local_storage_script = """
var localStorageData = {};
for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
    var key = localStorage.key(i);
    var value = localStorage.getItem(key);
    localStorageData[key] = value;
}
return localStorageData;
"""

local_storage_data = driver.execute_script(local_storage_script)
print("Local Storage Data:", local_storage_data)
```

You can get data in application like local storage, cooikes or session storage etc.